# ASP Repeater - Not able to add Class in DIV

Tags: css, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am using Repeater control in my asp.net file.
Everything is working fine except that DIV is distorted as it is throwing errors while adding class in DIV

- Below code it is working fine:(With distorted DIV)

  ```
  <ItemTemplate>
  <%# (Container.ItemIndex != 0 && Container.ItemIndex % 5 == 0) ? @"</div><div>" : string.Empty %>
  <asp:Image ID="imgGallery" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# /* your code  here */ %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>

  <FooterTemplate></div></FooterTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>

  This is what I want:(To add class in DIV but it's throwing error)

  <asp:Repeater ID="repImages" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate><div></HeaderTemplate>

  <ItemTemplate>
  <%# (Container.ItemIndex != 0 && Container.ItemIndex % 5 == 0) ? @"</div><div class="row"**>" : string.Empty %>
  <asp:Image ID="imgGallery" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# /* your code  here */ %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>

  <FooterTemplate></div></FooterTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
  ```

Comment: <%# (Container.ItemIndex != 0 && Container.ItemIndex % 5 == 0) ? @"</div><div class="row">" : string.Empty %>

Comment: Above after adding class="row" it is throwing error..If i remove it class="row" everything is fine.

Comment: Complete Code      <asp:Repeater ID="repImages" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate><div></HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
<%# (Container.ItemIndex != 0 && Container.ItemIndex % 5 == 0) ? @"</div><div class="row">" : string.Empty %>
<asp:Image ID="imgGallery" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# /* your code  here */ %>' />
</ItemTemplate>

<FooterTemplate></div></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

Comment: if i remove class="row"  everything is fine

Comment: No it will be different meaning ajmot...I cant put </div> as you mentioned .My grid will not work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the quotes with apostrophes

```
@"</div><div class='row'**>"
```